# Adding a string or char array to a byte vector

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm currently working on a class to create and read out packets send through the network, so far I have it working with 16bit and 8bit integers (Well unsigned but still).

Now the problem is I've tried numerous ways of copying it over but somehow the _buffer got mangled, it segfaulted, or the result was wrong.

I'd appreciate if someone could show me a working example.

My current code can be seen below.

Thanks, Xeross

## Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Packet.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "#################################" << endl;
    cout << "#       Internal Use Only       #" << endl;
    cout << "#     Codename PACKETSTORM      #" << endl;
    cout << "#################################" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    Packet packet = Packet();
    packet.SetOpcode(0x1f4d);

    cout << "Current opcode is: " << packet.GetOpcode() << endl << endl;

    packet.add(uint8_t(5))
          .add(uint16_t(4000))
          .add(uint8_t(5));

    for(uint8_t i=0; i<10;i++)
        printf("Byte %u = %x\n", i, packet._buffer[i]);

    printf("\nReading them out: \n1 = %u\n2 = %u\n3 = %u\n4 = %s",
        packet.readUint8(),
        packet.readUint16(),
        packet.readUint8());

    return 0;
}
```

## Packet.h

```
#ifndef _PACKET_H_
#define _PACKET_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Packet
{
    public:
        Packet() : m_opcode(0), _buffer(0), _wpos(0), _rpos(0) {}
        Packet(uint16_t opcode) : m_opcode(opcode), _buffer(0), _wpos(0), _rpos(0) {}

        uint16_t GetOpcode() { return m_opcode; }
        void SetOpcode(uint16_t opcode) { m_opcode = opcode; }

        Packet& add(uint8_t value)
        {
            if(_buffer.size() < _wpos + 1)
                _buffer.resize(_wpos + 1);

            memcpy(&_buffer[_wpos], &value, 1);
            _wpos += 1;

            return *this;
        }
        Packet& add(uint16_t value)
        {
            if(_buffer.size() < _wpos + 2)
                _buffer.resize(_wpos + 2);

            memcpy(&_buffer[_wpos], &value, 2);
            _wpos += 2;

            return *this;
        }

        uint8_t readUint8()
        {
            uint8_t result = _buffer[_rpos];
            _rpos += sizeof(uint8_t);
            return result;
        }
        uint16_t readUint16()
        {
            uint16_t result;
            memcpy(&result, &_buffer[_rpos], sizeof(uint16_t));

            _rpos += sizeof(uint16_t);
            return result;

        }

        uint16_t m_opcode;
        std::vector<uint8_t> _buffer;
    protected:

        size_t _wpos; // Write position
        size_t _rpos; // Read position
};

#endif // _PACKET_H_
```

Comment: Your question indicates a problem with appending a string or char array, but I don't see the code that attempts to do this.

Comment: I have removed my code for adding a string or char array, and would like someone to show me how it should be done. Else I could list 5 attempts at reading and writing

Comment: Don't mix printf and cout. use cout only instead.
Also stdio.h and it's likes are deprecated. Use <cstdio> for example.
For each C header just type c before it and remove the .h

Comment: Just to mention: you could also use a template method for add() and use sizeof instead of hard-coded type lengths. To avoid code repetition.

Comment: Hmm templates, I'd have to look into them.

So if I'd use a template it should work with any data type including arrays or ?

Comment: That is a formidable startup banner. Bravo.

Comment: @xeross: It will work with any type your code was designed for ;) In other words, if you only intend to add basic integers, keep it that way, and just replace the 1 and 2 with `sizeof(T)`, where `T` is the template type. Check this link to get started: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: @ereOn yes I already found that still thank your for the link, please read the comments I made on the first answer and see if you can help me out with that last bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using an std::vector for your buffer, you may as well let it keep track of the write position itself and avoid having to keep manually resizing it. You can also avoid writing multiple overloads of the add function by using a function template:

```
template <class T>
Packet& add(T value) {
    std::copy((uint8_t*) &value, ((uint8_t*) &value) + sizeof(T), std::back_inserter(_buffer));
    return *this;
}
```

Now you can write any POD type to your buffer.

implicitly:

```
int i = 5;
o.write(i);
```

or explictly:

```
o.write<int>(5);
```

To read from the buffer, you will need to keep track of a read position:

```
template <class T>
T read() {
    T result;
    uint8_t *p = &_buffer[_rpos];
    std::copy(p, p + sizeof(T), (uint8_t*) &result);
    _rpos += sizeof(T);
    return result;
}
```

You will need to explicitly pass a type parameter to read. i.e.

```
int i = o.read<int>();
```

Caveat: I have used this pattern often, but since I am typing this off the top of my head, there may be a few errors in the code.

Edit: I just noticed that you want to be able to add strings or other non-POD types to your buffer. You can do that via template specialization:

```
template <>
Packet& add(std::string s) {
    add(string.length());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i)
        add(string[i]);
    return *this;
}
```

This tells the compiler: if add is called with a string type, use this function instead of the generic add() function.

and to read a string:

```
template <>
std::string read<>() {
    size_t len = read<size_t>();
    std::string s;
    while (len--)
        s += read<char>();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: However I would need a seperate function for reading strings as those can be of variable length.

Thanks for the code I'll try it out now.

Comment: The second value should've been &value in 
copy((uint8_t*) &value, ((uint8_t*) &value) + sizeof(Type), back_inserter(_storage));

Comment: Hmm okay all the writes are working, normal reads are working, but it seems I can't add specialization with an argument like

template <>
string read<string>(size_t length) {}

any idea what I could use for this ?

Comment: @Ferruccio that way I can't specify a length for the string

Comment: You don't need to. The add method writes a length and string contents. The read method should read the length and build a string appropriately. I've added a string read method to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::string` as internal buffer and use [append()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/) when adding new elements.

Thus adding strings or const char* would be trivial.

Adding/writing uint8 can be done with casting it to char, writing uint16 - to char* with length sizeof(uint16_t).

```
void write_uint16( uint16_t val )
{
    m_strBuffer.append( (char*)(&var), sizeof(val) );
}
```

Reading uint16:

```
uint16_t read_int16()
{
    return ( *(uint16_t*)(m_strBuffer.c_str() + m_nOffset) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be attempting to print ten bytes out of the buffer when you've only added four, and thus you're running off the end of the vector. This could be causing your seg fault.

Also your printf is trying to print a character as an unsigned int with %x. You need to use `static_cast<unsigned>(packet._buffer[i])` as the parameter.

Stylistically:
`Packet packet = Packet();` could potentially result in two objects being constructed. Just use `Packet packet;`

Generally try to avoid protected attributes (protected methods are fine) as they reduce encapsulation of your class.

Comment: nope that wasn't causing the segfault, it printed just fine for some odd reason. I've now switched to using the template stuff Ferruccio proposed and that works pretty good, all that remains is the read function for strings.